# Luxon: faster calculation of fractional day

Tags: luxon

I need to calculate the fractional day: the fraction of the day that has passed since midnight. I also need an arbitrary time's year and month. These need to be in the context of UTC time. My app uses Luxon, so I used the following to calculate them, starting from `DateTime.now()` as an arbitrary example:

```
const luxonNow = DateTime.now();
const gt = luxonNow.setZone('utc');
const luxonY = gt.year;
const luxonM = gt.month;
const luxonMidnight = gt.startOf('day');
// Create an Interval beginning at midnight, ending now
// Find the decimal hours that have passed. Divide by 24 to find the fractional day passed
const luxonFrac = Interval.fromDateTimes(luxonMidnight, gt).length('hours') / 24;
luxonT = gt.day + luxonFrac;
```

This is in an area of code where performance is important. The code is fast: benchmarks show it takes anywhere up to 0.3ms, averaging 0.1ms.

Can I make it yet faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main bottlenecks are `.setZone` and `Interval.fromDateTimes().length()`.

`.setZone` doesn't have a single bottleneck that can be easily pointed out as a culprit. It looks like, when `.setZone('utc')` is called for the first time, Luxon creates a singleton UTC instance [here](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/src/zones/fixedOffsetZone.js#L17) that is then cached. Creating it for the first time seems to slow down `.setZone` by about 30%.

`Interval.fromDateTimes().length()` need to wait for the Intl API to return results [here](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/src/zones/IANAZone.js#L40) so that the correct time zone can be defined during the creation of the `DateTime`.

The native `Date` object supports conversion to UTC. Since this need is heavy on math and light on the need to define the local time zone, the native `Date` object can be used to achieve the same results:

```js
const dtNow = luxonNow.toJSDate();
// Get UTC version of date
const utc = new Date(
  dtNow.getUTCFullYear(),
  dtNow.getUTCMonth(),
  dtNow.getUTCDate(),
  dtNow.getUTCHours(),
  dtNow.getUTCMinutes(),
  dtNow.getUTCSeconds(),
  dtNow.getUTCMilliseconds()
);
const dtY = utc.getFullYear();
// Date months are 0-11
const dtM = utc.getMonth() + 1;
// For midnight:
// 1: Set to UTC now
const dtMidnight = new Date(utc.getTime());
// 2: Set hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds to 0 to obtain UTC midnight
dtMidnight.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
// 1 hour is 3.6e6 milliseconds.
// Milliseconds / 3.6e6 = equivalent hours.
// Equivalent hours / 24 = fractional day.
// Formula is ms/3.6e6/24. Slightly more efficient: ms/(3.6e6*24=86400000)
const fracDay = (utc.getTime() - dtMidnight.getTime()) / 86400000;
dtT = utc.getDate() + fracDay;
```

Benchmarks show that this method is anywhere up to 0.2ms (approaching Luxon's max), averaging just 0.008ms. It is 90-95% faster than Luxon.

Comment: The part about Intl shouldn't be true for the UTC zone. Luxon specifically handles that with a different implementation of the zone logic, which makes the zone calculations essentially free. Of course, there is other overhead to Luxon...

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that Intl was avoided for .setZone. I will edit the answer to better describe the bottleneck.